# IE 8 and missing background on div (again)

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, background-color

Here's my project:

[had to remove url because of spam-bot]

For a quick look, here's my CSS for the div in question:

```
#leftCol { width: 431px; height: 552px; background: #67b8b9; /* Fallback */ background: rgba(100,179,180,0.88); float: left; display: block; border-radius: 0px 24px 0px 0px; behavior: url('PIE-1/PIE.htc'); zoom: 1; }
```

The left column has a transparent solid background and one rounded corner. It looks fine everywhere, except some versions of IE 8. On my IE 8 (Win XP SP2) it's fine, dropping the transparency and just showing a solid color.

Today a co-worker showed me the page in their IE 8 and the background color is missing altogether, and I can recreate her results looking at the page through Adobe Browserlab, so it's 'something' but I don't know what.

Tried a separate CSS sheet for IE 8, I have no height:100%, overflow:hidden or any other properties that IE is known to choke on. So please tell me what I'm missing. If it helps, it looks fine in IE 7 too. In fact if I could get just IE 8 to behave like IE 7 I'd be happy enough.

Thanks!

Comment: IE doesn't support rgba (the 0.88 opacity on the background) as for the colour not displaying, try setting background-color too

Comment: @Andy, That's why the background: #67b8b9 is there. That's the fallback color and IE 7 picks it up just fine. If I change that attribute from background to background-color it doesn't change anything.

Comment: An important point here is that the background color is present in some versions of IE8, but not in others.  That says it's not the CSS.  What's different between those browsers / workstations?  (I'd look at compatibility mode first.)

Answer (score 0):

Seems the only fix I could find was to force IE8 to render like IE7 using the following meta tag

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7, IE=EmulateIE9" />
```

Doesn't really solve the problem as IE8 ought to be able to handle it. Gosh, how many times have you heard that before?

P.S. that tag tells IE 8 to render like IE 7 but leaves IE 9 alone to render as IE 9.